# RestSharp returns Status '0' while calling post method

Tags: c#, .net, rest, restsharp

Am facing issue while consuming restful service POST method. It is showing Status code 0, but while am trying to give same request from POSTMAN rest client (A google chrome extension) it works fine. below is the code am using to post some data.

```
var client = new RestClient(colorCreateUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
string jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actColorRequest);
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonRequest, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.AddBody(jsonRequest);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Request :
[image]

Error it shows

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you also show the POSTMan Request.

Comment: included request in the Question

Comment: What I meant to say is that, perhaps, the code shown is not performing an identical request as it is performing in POSTman and that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are using a self signed ssl certificate, check response.ErrorMessage for details. Either call an http endpoint or add the following code to allow all https certificates:

```
client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

I had the same issue today and used the above code to fix it.

Comment: Another option would be to check the https certificate and locally install it (or the root certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it seems the answer is not really helping. We should make the restClient throw any error. From there you can check the inner exception.

```
    var options = new RestClientOptions(_baseurl)
    {
        ThrowOnAnyError = true
    };
    _restClient = new RestClient(options);
```

Hope this can help anyone who face the same issues. Well, for me, it is just need to change to http.